# Tcl: Parsing input with strings in quotes

Tags: tcl

I have the following code to split stdin into a list of strings:

```
set cmd [string toupper [gets stdin]]
set items [split $cmd " "]
```

This splits the user input into a list (items) using the space as a delimiter. It works fine for simple input such as:

```
HELLO 1 2 3
```

What I get in `items`:

HELLO

1

2

But how can I get the quoted string in the example below to be become one item in the list (items):

```
"HELLO THERE" 1 2 3
```

What I want in `items`:

HELLO THERE

1

2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Tcl doesn't have strong types, the simplest way to do this is to just treat your stdin string like a list of strings.   No need to use `split` to convert a string into a list.

```
set cmd {"HELLO THERE" 1 2 3}
foreach item $cmd {
    puts $item
}

--> HELLO THERE
    1
    2
    3
```

Use `string is list` to check if your $cmd string can be treated as a list.

```
if {[string is list $cmd]} {
   puts "Can be a list"
} else {
   puts "Cannot be a list"
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This is where you get into building a more complex parser. The *first* step towards that is switching to using regular expressions.

```
regexp -all -inline {"[^\"]*"|[^\"\s]+} $inputData
```

That will do the right thing... provided the input is well-formed and only uses double quotes for quoting. It also doesn't strip the quotes off the outside of the "words"; you'll want to use `string trim $word \"` to clean that up.

---

If this is a command that you are parsing, use a safe interpreter. Then you can allow Tcl syntax to be used without exposing the guts of your code. I'm pretty sure there are answers here on how to do that already.